# Can't unrar file

Tags: linux, terminal, unrar

So I used unrar-free to unrar a file that I wanted to extract. When I gave the command in the CMD it showed me this:

```
unrar 0.0.1  Copyright (C) 2004  Ben Asselstine, Jeroen Dekkers


Extracting from /home/pi/Downloads/_Getintopc.com_Toon_Boom_Harmony_Premium_17.0.0_Build_14765x64.rar

All OK
```

Even though it looks like It actually extracted something, it didn't. When I went to my downloads file, I clicked 'Extract here' but It gave me an error saying that it couldn't extract the file.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not questions about using or setting up Linux. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Super User](http://superuser.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Could you check if that rar file is maybe empty (or partially downloaded)? For reference, here is what it would have printed if it *did* find any files in that archive:

```
wald@panther:~/Projects/pyQuiri$ unrar /home/wald/Downloads/sample.rar

unrar 0.0.1  Copyright (C) 2004  Ben Asselstine, Jeroen Dekkers


Extracting from /home/wald/Downloads/sample.rar

Extracting  DSCF1842.JPG                                              OK        
Extracting  DSCF1842.JPG.id-4317106112_av666@weekendwarrior55.com     OK        
All OK
```

Comment: Thanks, I think there should be something in the file, but again, linux is different. So I think there probably isn't anything inside.